# forcing element in same line regardless content

Tags: html, css

I searched here already and tried some accepted solutions but not worked for my case. I have listed some html and I need these elements both wrapper element and inner elements in single line.
here how it looks now and html;

[image]

html;

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="well">
                            <ul class="media-list">
                                <li class="media">
                                    <a class="toggle-area pull-left" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <img class="media-object" alt="Mali Sistemler" src="/Content/img/login/mali_hizmetler.png">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4 class="toggle-area media-heading"><span style="width: 95%;">Mali Sistemler</span><i class="fa fa-parent-container fa-plus-square pull-right"></i></h4>
                                        <div class="container-menus" style="display:none;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="well">... </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="well">
                            <ul class="media-list">
                                <li class="media">
                                    <a class="toggle-area pull-left" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <img class="media-object" alt="Denetim Sistemleri" src="/Content/img/login/denetim.png">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4 class="toggle-area media-heading"><span style="width: 95%;">Denetim Sistemleri</span><i class="fa fa-parent-container fa-plus-square pull-right"></i></h4>
                                        <div class="container-menus" style="display:none;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="well">... </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequences of `white-space` will collapse into a single `white-space`. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a `<br>` tag is encountered

Use `white-space:nowrap`

Update css

```
.media-body, .media-left, .media-right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Add this */
}
```

Working fiddle

**[fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/28/)**

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, appreciated it!

Comment: can you also help about setting these containers in same line horizantally. I edited image you see, second containers broken because 3th containers heigth lower. how to set all containres in a row horizantally ordered

Comment: okay let me check and i will post as soon as possible, you only two containers if you need in a row use `flex` to get it

Comment: use `col-xs-4` for horizontally

Comment: Its ok now. Thank you!